# UndefinedStepException when run test using Cucumber JVM

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, appium

I develop a test for the mobile application using Cucumber+Junit+Appium. When I try to run a test using cucumber and JUnit runner I receive: `io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The step "I install the application" is undefined. You can implement it using the snippet(s) below:`

I tried some of the solutions from the medium blog and stack question, but this doesn't help.

I have a project structure:

```
src
 |-main
 |--java
 |---{project-name}
 |----config
 |----models
 |----screens
 |----services
 |-test
 |--java
 |---{project-name}
 |----helpers
 |----stepDefinitions
 |-----LoginStep.java
 |-----BaseStep.java
 |-----LoginStep.java
 |----RunCucumber.java
 |--resources
 |---feature
 |----Login.feature
```

RunCucumber.java

```
package com.mobile.automation.framework;

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.mobile.automation.framework.module.ServiceModules;
import com.mobile.automation.framework.service.AppiumServer;
import com.mobile.automation.framework.config.drivers.DriverFactory;
import com.mobile.automation.framework.module.ScreensModule;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        strict = true,
        monochrome = true,
        glue = "src.test.java.com.mobile.automation.framework.stepDefinition",
        features = "src/test/resources/feature",
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html",
                "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                "junit:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.xml"})
public class RunCucumber {
    public static AppiumDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUpDriver() {
        init();
        new AppiumServer().startServer();
        driver = new DriverFactory().getDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDownDriver() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
            new AppiumServer().stopServer();
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        Guice.createInjector(
                new ScreensModule(driver),
                new ServiceModules(driver)
        ).injectMembers(this);
    }
}
```

Login.feature

```
Feature: Sign In feature

  Background:
    Given I install application
    And I enable all network activity
    Then I am on Sign Page

  Scenario: Sign In scenario
    Given I am go to the Login Page
    And I fill valid user data using "Config"
    And I click sign in button

    Then I am login in the application
```

LoginStep.java

```
package com.mobile.automation.framework.stepDefinition;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.mobile.automation.framework.config.ProjectConfig;
import com.mobile.automation.framework.models.User;
import com.mobile.automation.framework.screens.DashboardScreen;
import com.mobile.automation.framework.screens.SignInScreen;
import io.cucumber.java.ParameterType;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

/**
 * @author Tomash Gombosh
 */
public class LoginStep {
    @Inject
    private SignInScreen signInScreen;
    @Inject
    private DashboardScreen dashboardScreen;

    @Given("^I am go to the Login Page$")
    public void iAmGoToTheLoginPage() {
        dashboardScreen.tapLogin();
    }

    @And("I fill valid user data using {string} {string}")
    public void iFillValidUserDataUsing(String userName, String password) {
        signInScreen.fillLogin(userName, password);
    }

    @And("I fill valid user data using {string}")
    @ParameterType("Config")
    public void iFillValidUserDataUsing() {
        signInScreen.fillLogin(new User(data -> {
            data.setEmail(new ProjectConfig().getBaseUser());
            data.setPassword(new ProjectConfig().getBaseUserPassword());
        }));
    }

    @And("I click sign in button")
    public void iClickSignInButton() {
        signInScreen.clickLogin();
    }

    @Then("I am login in the application")
    public void iAmLoginInTheApplication() {
        assertThat(signInScreen.isDisplayed()).isEqualTo(true);
    }

}
```

Some of the steps on the Login class is missing, but that is because I want to put all the code to the question.

I expected to run that feature, but actually that is not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically `src.test.java` is not part of the package name. Try using:

```
glue = "com.mobile.automation.framework.stepDefinition",
```

And because Cucumber will search the runners package for glue by default can also remove the glue entirely.

Comment: I remove glue from the Cucumber options and remove `src.test.java` from the feature parameter of the Cucumber options,  but now I receive `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseDir must exist: /resources/feature`, maybe I have pasted my feature file in the wrong location?

Comment: Your feature path was fine. Why did you change it? Either `src/test/resources/feature` or `classpath:feature` will work.

Answer (score 0):

New here myself working on Junit Runner, I agree with @M.P.Korstanje with classpath. Although I just had to change glue to refer the stepDefs with classpath too - wasn't getting recognized before.

So basically this is what I did to catch the necessary files to be triggered

```
feature = { "classpath:path-from-repo-root.feature" },
glue = { "classpath:reference-to-stepDef-folder" }
```

Bear in mind: for glue - I used to the reference to the folder containing the stepDefs and not the stepDef file itself. Hope this helps someone. Thanks