# Maven does not see cucumber step definitions

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

My problem is following: I have a Cucumber and java project in eclipse. I can run it successfully. But when I try to run it using maven, no step definition is found and the error message is "You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:", which are, of course, implemented.
My pom.xml looks like this:

```
  <groupId>Cucumber_Selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>Cucumber_Selenium</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Cucumber_Selenium</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
       <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
       <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
       <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
       <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
       <version>5.3.0</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
       <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
       <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
       <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
       <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
       <version>5.3.0</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The runner class has this content:

```
package runners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"}, features = {"src/test/java/features/"}, glue = {"src/test/java/stepsdefinitions"})
public class RunnerTest {
}
```

The structure of project in eclipse is this:
[image]

I would appreciate your help as I found no good solution until now. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103843/undefinedstepexception-when-run-test-using-cucumber-jvm/60104245

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UndefinedStepException when run test using Cucumber JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103843/undefinedstepexception-when-run-test-using-cucumber-jvm)

Comment: Unfortunately is not working.

Comment: is the glue added to the pom?

Comment: If the glue is added to the pom, could you also try to modify in the runner class as following: features = {"src\\test\\java\\features"}, glue = {"src.test.java.stepsdefinitions"}

Comment: The solution was to modify glue like this: glue = {"stepsdefinitions", "common", "hooks", "pages"}. stepsdefinitions should be written without the absolute path. The others are dependencies, and should be written in glue, otherwise, you'll get  io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException.